Как пролистать все слайды при нажатии?
Необходимо реализовать при нажатии на кнопку что бы слайдер прошел весь круг от первого слайда и вернулся обратно на исходную позицию и так каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку.
Методам библиотеки slideTo можно перейти к последнему слайду, но это будет не полный круг, необходимо каждый раз возвращаться на первый, то что реализовал сейчас выглядит немного топорно:
https://jsfiddle.net/vakarchuk/uc6r4fs9/214/
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  loop: true,
});
    
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  swiper.slideTo(8, 1000, false);
  setTimeout(() => { swiper.slideTo(0, 1, false); }, 1000);
}); 

P.S. Может быть на slickslider решение...
